# Stop ssh config on first match

Tags: ssh

I have a added a local proxy for all my hosts in my .ssh config, however I want to shell into my local vm without the proxy command.  Output of my ssh attempt:

```
debug1: /Users/bbarbour/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for local.dev
debug1: /Users/bbarbour/.ssh/config line 65: Applying options for *
```

Given the following ssh config how do I prevent the ProxyCommand from being applied to the local.dev entry?

```
Host local.dev
    HostName dev.myserver.com
    User developer
...
Host *
    ProxyCommand /usr/local/bin/corkscrew 127.0.0.1 8840 %h %p
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can exclude local.dev from ProxyCommand, using `!` before it:

```
Host * !local.dev
    ProxyCommand /usr/local/bin/corkscrew 127.0.0.1 8840 %h %p
```

From [ssh_config](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5) documentation:

> **If more than one pattern is provided, they should be separated by whitespace.**
>
> **A pattern entry may be negated by prefixing it with an exclamation mark (`!')**.  If a negated entry is matched, then the Host
>          entry is ignored, regardless of whether any other patterns on the
>          line match.  Negated matches are therefore useful to provide
>          exceptions for wildcard matches.

The documentation also said:

> For each parameter, **the first obtained value will be used**.     The
>   configuration files contain sections separated by ``Host''
>   specifications, and
>        that section is only applied for hosts that match one of the patterns
>        given in the specification.  The matched host name   is the one given on
>        the command line.

So, you can also disable ProxyCommand for local.dev by override value that you have defined in `Host *`:

```
Host local.dev
    HostName dev.myserver.com
    User developer
    ProxyCommand none
```

Answer (score 9):

An option in the config file is applied the first time it matches. Since you don't have any ProxyCommand in the host entry, the one in your `*` entry will be used.

There are two ways to get around this:

- For the hosts where you don't want to use the proxy command, simply add the line

```
    ProxyCommand none
```

- For the `*` entry, note specifically that the entry should not apply to the host `local.dev` by negating it with a `!`

```
    Host !local.dev *
```

Comment: to separate multiple hosts use space. comma(,) did not work for me.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 17.10
Release: 17.10
Codename: artful

Comment: Thanks @ArunaFromLK - I can't believe I missed that, and that nobody else has spotted it in 3,5 years! I've updated the answer now.