# ssh config from Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't work on 14.04.4

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, configuration, proxy, ssh-config

I setup a new Ubuntu 14.04.4 server to replace a 12.04 machine, but the new server is having problems with the old ssh config.  I can ssh without the config, and can even ssh through a bastion server with no problem from the command line.  For example,

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p bastion.my.company.com" lab123.my.company.com
```

But if I create a `/home/myname/.ssh/config` file with the following settings, I'm having problems.

```
ServerAliveInterval 150
ServerAliveCountMax 6

ControlMaster auto
ControlPath /tmp/ssh_%h_%p_%r

Host *.my.company.com
User   myname
IdentityFile /home/myname/.ssh/mykey.pem
ProxyCommand ssh bastion -W %h:%p
ForwardAgent yes

Host bastion
Hostname        bastion.my.company.com
User            myname
IdentityFile    /home/myname/.ssh/mykey.pem
```

When I try to use ssh with the config above, I get hundreds of ssh processes like the following:

```
myname 29855 29854  0 12:24 pts/6    00:00:00 ssh bastion -W bastion.my.company.com:22
myname 29856 29855  0 12:24 pts/6    00:00:00 ssh bastion -W bastion.my.company.com:22
myname 29857 29856  0 12:24 pts/6    00:00:00 ssh bastion -W bastion.my.company.com:22
myname 29858 29857  0 12:24 pts/6    00:00:00 ssh bastion -W bastion.my.company.com:22
```

`ssh` just hangs until I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, and then all the ssh processes die.

A trace of the last few lines of every processes looks like:

```
....
write(4, "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2"..., 43) = 43
read(5, 0xbfe08efc, 1)                  = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGINT {si_signo=SIGINT, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
+++ killed by SIGINT +++
```

A look further up in the trace shows the file handles are from the following:

```
...
socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0)        = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/tmp/ssh_bastion.my.company.com_22_myname"}, 57) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
pipe([3, 4])                            = 0
pipe([5, 6])                            = 0
..
```

It seems strange that there's no socket file in /tmp, and there's no bind in the trace.

Comment: Have you tried excluding `bastion.my.company.com` from the wildcard host match e.g. `Host *.my.company.com !bastion.my.company.com` as described here [Stop ssh config on first match](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152265/65304)

Comment: I also tried changing "ControlPath /tmp/ssh_%h_%p_%r" to "ControlPath /tmp/ssh_control_socket" incase it didn't like some character in one of the variables.  I don't understand why it's not creating the socket..

Comment: And `ssh -v` says?

Comment: The solution was your first suggestion to exclude bastion from Host -  *.my.company.com !bastion.my.company.com    Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The solution was provided in a comment by steeldriver, whom suggested I exclude  bastion.my.company.com from the wildcard host match.

For example,

```
ServerAliveInterval 150
ServerAliveCountMax 6

ControlMaster auto
ControlPath /tmp/ssh_%h_%p_%r

Host *.my.company.com !bastion.my.company.com
User   myname
IdentityFile /home/myname/.ssh/mykey.pem
ProxyCommand ssh bastion -W %h:%p
ForwardAgent yes

Host bastion
Hostname        bastion.my.company.com
User            myname
IdentityFile    /home/myname/.ssh/mykey.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

> `ControlPath /tmp/ssh_%h_%p_%r`

This is pretty bad idea to put your Control sockets into the "public-accessible" `/tmp`. It should be in some safe directory, where no other users can access.

The behavior looks like there was changed default of `CanonicalizeHostname`. What does this option defaults to in your system? Try to disable it: `CanonicalizeHostname no`.

Setting `LogLevel DEBUG3` is also good start with debugging problems with `ssh`. Can you set this option in you configuration and post the logs?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but today I was able to get ssh working by excluding bastion.my.company.com from the wildcard host match.  My original change to the config file was wrong, so it didn't work (wondering if I should remove the comment from yesterday).